# Access DB Query to filter column data by grouping the substring and choosing the maximum

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access

DB Table 'LabelInfo'

```
ID      Labels    
1       TRPKLM003 
2       JPRECM001 
3       MNTORM005 
4       JPRECM004 
5       MNTORM002 
6       JPRECM003 
7       TRPKLM002 
8       TRPKLM004
```

Column label is of fixed length. I would like to return the following data as results:

```
TRPKLM004
MNTORM005
JPRECM004
```

I would to write an  access query that can returns me only the rows by grouping matching first 6 characters and max value of rest of the 3 characters. or If I am returning all the rows from the table, I would like an optimized way to filter results in C#

Comment: I think your question is way to vague.

Comment: So far I m retreving all the rows order by desc. that just gives me data in sorted way. then in my code I am filtering data by running a for loop over each row comparing substring(label, 0, 6) of label with rest of items . As its already sorted if its cannot find the same label then returning that item.. but this is comparing each row with all the rows and taking too much time to return results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The db engine can split out the two components of the `Labels` field.

```
SELECT
    Left(Labels, 6) AS prefix_string
    Val(Right(Labels, 3)) AS suffix_nmbr
FROM LabelInfo;
```

Use that as a subquery for a `GROUP BY` query.

```
SELECT
    sub.prefix_string,
    Max(sub.suffix_nmbr) AS MaxOfSuffix_nmbr
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            Left(Labels, 6) AS prefix_string
            Val(Right(Labels, 3)) AS suffix_nmbr
        FROM LabelInfo
    ) AS sub
GROUP BY sub.prefix_string;
```

If it's not convenient to recombine the two parts in your c# client-side code, you can have the db engine do it with everything so far as a subquery.

```
SELECT
    sub2.prefix_string
        & Format(sub2.MaxOfSuffix_nmbr, '000')
        AS labels_alias
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            sub1.prefix_string,
            Max(sub1.suffix_nmbr) AS MaxOfSuffix_nmbr
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    Left(Labels, 6) AS prefix_string
                    Val(Right(Labels, 3)) AS suffix_nmbr
                FROM LabelInfo
            ) AS sub1
        GROUP BY sub1.prefix_string
    ) AS sub2;
```

Comment: Thanks for the query .. you are awesome !! only problem is my prefix is getting truncated like ... 007 is returned as 7 and 003 as 3 .. can I have it as full 3 chars.. as I need the whole string as result

Comment: That's because I cast the string portion as a number.  You can convert  it back to a "000"-formatted string and concatenate that with the "prefix_string" piece.  See if the last (untested) query version returns what you want.

Comment: yep.. Got it !! thank you .. I was struggling for many hours to get it exactly working .. !! you saved lot of time !!